# livereload inject in html

Tags: node.js, gulp, livereload

First... Sorry for my english... I ll try to explain well...

Im using "tapestry". This framework lets you show an repository components and you can see the code html and his appearance...

Im trying to post my repository but the server is crashing with the livereload.js for the port....

I dont need this code in my index.html with a .jade but i dont know how I can delete this code injected:

script src=//localhost:35729/livereload.js/script

Im looking for all the proyect but i cant find it.
I dont mnow what I can do... I try to delete this code with js but livereload is downloadinh on my local... But in my server public crash...

Could someone helps me? Pls.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in gulpfile deleting the embedlr = require('gulp-embedlr') and the package.json deleting "gulp-embedlr": "~0.5.2",